UWP and Fulltrustprocess and IPC - Dynamic Named pipe name
We have the UWP app which needs to communicate to the full trust process for file conversions.
There would be multiple file conversions and the UWP app can start multiple instances of full trust process.
UWP app calls await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync() to start the full trust process. The communication between the UWP app and the full-trust process is done through named pipes.
The UWP needs to pass the dynamically generated named pipe server name to the fully trusted process and through that, the full trusted process can start the server. From the UWP app the named pipe client uses this server name to connect to the pipe server. So for each file conversion the pipe server name changes and respective client connects to the respective server through this name.
The pipe server name is a combination of AppName+ GUID.
In the main method , the pipe server name is read from the command line params, then start the server and listen to the client request.
The issue is how to pass the dynamic Namedpipe server name to the full trust process main method using which the client can connect?
Thanks

"In the main method , the pipe server name is read from the command line params, then start the server and listen to the client request." Isn't Namedpipe server name already obtained through parameters here?

the fulltrustprocess is started through FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync() . How can i pass the dynamically generated pipe servername here and get it through command line params?

https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/ Currently, it is not possible to pass dynamic values, only static values ​​that have been set in advance.

Currently, it is not possible to pass dynamic values through appservice in UWP, only static values ​​that have been set in advance.
Related examples can be found here.
